# Snowflake ODBC works with Azure and fail with AWS

Tags: odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created an azure Snowflake trial account and an odbc dsn, it works.
Then I had to create a Snowflake trial in AWS to use the Snowflake training.
When creating a DSN it fails with this error; Incorrect username or password was specified.
For Azure, I use ..snowflakecomputing.com, this works.
For AWS I use .snowflakecomputing.com, I get the user error.
I tried other combinations but hten I always get a host unresolved error.
..snowflakecomputing.com
.sg..aws.snowflakecomputing.com
Thanks for hints

Comment: ODBC connectivity is not affected by which cloud deployment you use. It is basically looking up the right connection details. Please check if the ODBC DNS is configured for the right AWS account or it is still having the values for Azure one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/organizations-connect.html your Snowflake URL / servername is in this format

```
https://<account_locator>.<region>.<cloud>.snowflakecomputing.com
```

The cloud is not needed if using AWS, but is if using Azure or GCP. The region is not needed if us-east1 but otherwise must be specified.

Now, it doesn't matter where you are trying to connect to Snowflake from - it only matters where your Snowflake instance is.

So, if you made your Snowflake instances in AWS it is the exact same URL / server name whether you connect to it via the web console, a command-line tool, ODBC from an AWS application, JDBC from an Azure application, or anything else.

Thus, if you made the Snowflake account in AWS you will use something like

```
https://FV23210.ap-southeast2.snowflakecomputing.com
```

no matter where you call it from; if you made the Snowflake account in Azure you will use something like

```
https://FV23210.ap-southeast2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com
```

no matter where you call it from.

Comment: I created a new AWS trial and this time the odbc works. I can access the first trial from the web interface but not from odbc. I am not sure what I did to it, anyways since the new trial works, I am fine. Thanks for the help, @Srinath Menon pointed me to the right direction and DavidMWilliams reiterated the correct connection string requirement.